# How to run command line version of lc3 with an input .asm program and analyzie it using gdb?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb, lc3

I am a CS student learning how to program in C.
LC3 is a fake assembly language for teaching purposes.

> computer-name> gdb mysim -norun testfde.obj

This yields a problem, the command is not recognized.
`mysim` is the c executable, `testfde.obj` is the lc3 assembly executable, `-norun` means make the `mysim` execution be command line.

I want to run `mysim -norun` with `testfde.obj` and analyze it using gdb, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to run mysim -norun with testfde.obj and analyze it using gdb, how would I do this?

```
gdb --args mysim -norun testfde.obj
(gdb) run
```

Alternatively:

```
gdb mysim
(gdb) run -norun testfde.obj
```